# Enable uiimageview dragging across horizontal uiscrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

In my ViewController I have a fixed UIImageView above a UIScrollView (there is no parent child relationship)

When the user drags across the screen the image updates and the pagination increases, but there is no scrolling effect.

How can I enable horizontal animation and fade out?

Alternatively, if I create uiimageview and add subview programatically the scroll effect works, but how can I center each image?

Thanks